# How to create AMI from EBS snapshot with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I know that AMI can be created from EBS snapshot on EC2 console.

I want to operate this AMI creation not on the AWS console but with the AWS CLI command.

The `aws ec2 copy-image` command does not have any EBS Snapshot option to specify. Is there any way to do this with CLI or calling APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Creating an Amazon EBS-Backed Linux AMI - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html):

> **To create an AMI from a snapshot using the command line**
>
> You can use one of the following commands. For more information about these command line interfaces, see Accessing Amazon EC2.
>
> - [register-image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/register-image.html) (AWS CLI)
> - [Register-EC2Image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Register-EC2Image.html) (AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell)

The `register-image` documentation page says:

> You can also use `RegisterImage` to create an Amazon EBS-backed Linux AMI from a snapshot of a root device volume.

Answer (score 10):

after I had the same problem and was looking for the simple example (because the documentation like linked in above is a little bit confused written) - and unfortunately could not find any, I post a simple example aws-cli call.

**A real world example:**

```
aws ec2 register-image --name "YOUR_DESCRIPTION" --region=eu-west-1 --description "AMI_from_snapshot_EBS" --block-device-mappings DeviceName="/dev/sda",Ebs={SnapshotId="snap-0070070007"} --root-device-name "/dev/sda1"
```

**OUTPUT** should be something like this:

```
{
    "ImageId": "ami-0022d44252254fffff7"
}
```